# PermanentTaskFailure: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (due to DateTimePropety?)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pickle, deferred

Following the ["Background work with the deferred library"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred) article, I created a set of scheduled tasks to help maintain our app. They each flush old entities of a specific type.

In one case, instead of using the standard ndb model `key` property (for tracking which records have been processed), we use a non-key property of type `DateTimeProperty`. When we do this, and we hit the `DeadlineExceededError`, the deferred instance of the method dies during the unpickling of the task arguments made in the [deferred.run method](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py#145).

Relevant code in our base class:

```
def _continue(self, start_key, batch_size):
    # ...
    except DeadlineExceededError:
        if self._numBatches > 0:
            self.Log("Deferring to a new instance of the process.")
            deferred.defer(self._continue, start_key, batchSize)
        else:
            self.LogWarning("No batches were completely processed. This process will terminate to prevent continuous operation.")
            raise deferred.PermanentTaskFailure("DeadlineExceededError occurred before any batches could be completely processed.")
    self.Finish()
```

When the deferred copy of the method kicks in, it produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 310, in post
        self.run_from_request()
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 305, in run_from_request
        run(self.request.body)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 145, in run
        raise PermanentTaskFailure(e)
    PermanentTaskFailure: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

More digging (`pdb` through the `deferred` and `pickle` library) unveils a bit more details:

```
1080        def load_newobj(self):
1081            args = self.stack.pop()
1082            cls = self.stack[-1]
1083 ->         obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
1084            self.stack[-1] = obj
1085        dispatch[NEWOBJ] = load_newobj
```

and

```
(Pdb) pp args
      ()
(Pdb) pp cls
      <class 'google.appengine.ext.ndb.query.FilterNode'>
(Pdb) n
      TypeError: '__new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)'
      > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py(1083)load_newobj()
```

I'll be digging more, but the basic questions now seem to be:

1. Aside from pdb, how could one gain more info on a failure happening during this stage (ie: deferred.run and unpickling) ?
2. I found some hints online about the ability to override `deferred.TaskHandler` (introduced in [v.1.6.3 - Feb 28, 2012](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.6.3_-_February_28,_2012)), which may help with the first question, but could not find any example on how to do this.
3. Seems like ndb FilterNodes with a DateTimeProperty may not be picklable by default (or properly handled). Is that so?

Comment: Based on the error trace, the creation of 'PermanentTaskFailure' is causing the error, not the deferred call. For some reason it expects 4 arguments, not 1. As this derives from 'Exception', I am unsure why this would be the case unless something had overridden Exception somewhere.

Comment: In my experience, deferreds have methods like `.resolve()`, `.reject()`, and `.then()`. The methods `deferred.defer` and `deferred.PermanentTaskFailure` make me wonder if the [deferred] tag is really appropriate here.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - thanks for your comment. I understand the concern. However, the question is also about the "deferred" library provided by GAE (so the tag could be appropriate). I'm going to monitor here and look for guidance from the rest in this regard.

Comment: @ChrisC73 thanks for the suggestion.. I've reformatted the stack trace in my Q to preserve the indentation. However, even looking at the code involved [from the deferred lib source](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py) I'm still in the dark.
The PermanentTaskFailure raised at line 145 is defined in the same source file and doesn't seem to add anything to Error (and the base python Exception). I'll keep on looking for any monkey-patchiong that may have snuck in, but I don't think I'll find any in our app :(

Comment: What version of appengine launcher are you using?

Comment: @rdodev: originally 1.9.22 but as of this morning 1.9.23 (btw all of this happens on the live environment.. can't get actual DeadlineExceededErrors on the local dev SDK anyway)

Comment: Looking at the source code, it would appear that the issue is that it cannot unpickle the payload. `func, args, kwds = pickle.loads(data)` if unpickling fails, it then throws the permanent exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen from the source of `deferred.py`, you've analyzed quite well together with @rdodev to realize that the problem is when attempting to un-pickle the `data` argument to `run()`. That in turn was being called from `run_from_request()`, so the thing that's un-pickled here is the request payload itself, which is created when you call `deferred.defer()`.

It's possible that for the `DateTimeProperty` to be un-pickled, the pickle module needs to call the constructor for it (`__new__`), but this isn't available or presents a different method signature at that time than when it was pickled, resulting in the exception you see, which bubbles up to be caught and presents to you as `PermanentTaskFailure`.

Overall, this might be worth posting as a defect report to the [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) if you can produce an example app which reliably reproduces the behaviour.

Other than that, as a work-around for now, I'd use something which doesn't cause the error, such as the string representation of the `DateTimeProperty`, or a regular `datetime.datetime` object, or even another `ndb.Property` class which doesn't cause the issue. You could also try to use the [taskqueue library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push) itself, which is quite easy to use and shouldn't represent a significant departure from your current use-case.

Comment: Thank you @Nick (and apologies for x-posting to the GAE forum).
I've just updated the Q with details I uncovered, which seem to be in-line with your suggestions.
I'm going to dig some more to see if I find an easy work-around (I think I tried to pass the data as a string instead of datetime but that failed, I'll try again now that I can monitor the low-level unpickling).
I'd like to reduce our case down before submitting it as an actual issue to the official tracker of course. Thanks again for keeping an eye here!